# Javascript check undefined issue

Tags: javascript

The following code throws an error message in the console and i don't understand this logic, because in my code you can see i have written if statements which should first check if the objects exist.

```js
if (typeof document.getElementById("trbrok0").checked != "undefined") document.getElementById("trbrok0").checked = false;
if (typeof document.getElementById("trbrok1").checked != "undefined") document.getElementById("trbrok1").checked = false;
if (typeof document.getElementById("trbrok2").checked != "undefined") document.getElementById("trbrok2").checked = false;
if (typeof document.getElementById("trbrok3").checked != "undefined") document.getElementById("trbrok3").checked = false;
```

Like you can see we should first check if the object exists and then try to change the value of "checked" property in the object.
But I always get the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
```

Comment: the elements you try to access do not exist

Comment: You are trying to get `checked` property from `null`

Answer (score 5):

Because `document.getElementById("trbrok0")` returns a DOM node and if it doesn't exist it returns `null`. `null` doesn't have a property `checked` so `document.getElementById("trbrok0").checked` throws the error.

The fix would be to add a check if the node exists first with `if(document.getElementById("trbrok0")!= null){ }`

Comment: ok great so anyway there is a logic to check this good to know

Answer (score 1):

> Have a look

```js
function checkNullAndSetVal(id, val) {
  if (document.getElementById(id) == null) {
    console.log(id + ", Null or Undefined");
    return;
  }

  document.getElementById(id)["checked"] = val;
  console.log("Successfully Updated: ", id);
}

checkNullAndSetVal("trbrok0", false);
checkNullAndSetVal("trbrok1", true);
checkNullAndSetVal("trbrok2", false);
checkNullAndSetVal("trbrok3", true);
```

```html
<input id="trbrok2" type="checkbox" name="trbrok" value="2">
<input id="trbrok3" type="checkbox" name="trbrok" value="3">
```

> Explanation:

1. if you check for null with double equals to (==), then it check for both null & undefined
2. Use a function to reduce repetition of code.
3. Use square bracket syntax to create non existing properties in an object. e.g obj["newProperty"] = "Some Value";

Answer (score 0):

When you check the type of the `checked`, the element, selected by `document.getElementById` doesn't exist, and that's why:

```
Cannot read property 'checked' of null
```

because `null` doesn't have a property named `checked`.